# svg image element not shown on mobile

Tags: svg

I have been trying to get the cross browser compatability working of my svg project. I had a friend test my link on a mobile, but he sais the image doesn't load and he gets a black screen (I assume the black he refers too, is the `rect` in the background). Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code or why the image doesn't display properly on mobile?

**svg**

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 3000 2500">
<g transform="translate(225,50)">
  <rect width="2550" height="1925" id="background-rect"></rect>
  <image href="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" width="2550" height="1925"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/RobMo/pen/aVvKEP

*PS: Just an idea: It might have to do with me not declaring a namespace. I can't test it right now, but that might be what is causing this. Or maybe help people provide inspiration for an answer :).*

**PPS: To use the `<img>` tag you need to use xlink:href instead of just href. I should've decared the namespace in the svg tag as well.**

Comment: Is your SVG an external image, or inlined in the HTML page?  If the former, what HTML tag are you using to embed it (`<img>`, `<object>` etc).

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you add a namespace?

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 3000 2500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <g transform="translate(225,50)">
      <rect width="2550" height="1925" id="background-rect"></rect>
      <image href="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" width="2550" height="1925"></image>
   </g>
</svg>
```

REF - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image